# Cairo docker build fails due to missing pixman dependency

Tags: docker, cairo

I'm upgrading a docker image I have to use latest Cairo, cairo-1.17.2.
When I try to build it, I get the following error:

```
#12 8.793 checking for pixman... no
#12 8.801 checking whether cairo's image surface backend feature could be enabled... no 

(requires pixman-1 >= 0.36.0 https://cairographics.org/releases/)
#12 8.802 configure: error: mandatory image surface backend feature could not be enabled
```

The dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:10.15

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    python3-setuptools \
    wget \
    poppler-utils \
    jq \
    pdftk \
    ghostscript \
    ffmpeg \
    build-essential cmake libfontforge-dev wget \
    libpoppler-private-dev \
    pkg-config \
    cmake \
    make \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    libcairo-dev \
    libspiro-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libpoppler-dev \
    libpango1.0-dev \
    libfontforge-dev \
    poppler-data \
    openjdk-8-jre-headless \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip \
    && apt-get clean

RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install --upgrade awscli

WORKDIR /tmp

ADD lib/cairo-1.17.2.tar.xz /tmp
WORKDIR /tmp/cairo-1.17.2
RUN ./configure --prefix=/tmp/cairob && make && make install
RUN cp -r /tmp/cairob/lib/* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I searched for perhaps installing pixman using `apt-get` but was unable to find it.

Please advise.

Comment: Try `libpixman-1-dev`?

Comment: tried it now, added this to the installments in the begging, same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2020-December/029164.html and https://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2020-December/029165.html

Basically: I guess you need to either build pixman yourself or get a less ancient base image.